# Connection to Google Bigtable in Google Dataproc using HBase odbc driver

Tags: odbc, hbase, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

Has anyone already made a connection to Google Bigtable in Google Cloud Dataproc using any available HBase odbc driver? If yes, can you tell which ODBC you've used? Thanks

Comment: Dataproc is a system that includes Spark, Hadoop and other OSS systems.  Which open source system are you using?  FWIW, we have some samples at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples that may help.

Comment: We don't have any setup for now aside from using BigQuery ODBC to read data, we're still looking on how to integrate this within a .Net application using an ODBC or anything that implements an IDbConnection.

Comment: We're building a new .Net client for Cloud Bigtable at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet. That will allow .Net developers to use Cloud Bigtable. Cloud Bigtable concepts don't easily map to SQL, which makes ODBC/JDBC drivers difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Solomon in the comments, we don't have a native ODBC or JDBC driver for Google Cloud Bigtable. If you're building a .NET application and want to interact with Bigtable we recommend using the native client here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet

Another approach that may work would be to use BigQuery which does have [ODBC support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/) and combine that with BigQuery's support for [federated data access to Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources). That's a bit of a Rube Goldberg construction though, so it may be more painful to set up and debug.